# Why does Sql Server makes this bad query plan choice?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, execution-plan

Sql Server gives me a bad query plan and I'm trying to understand why that is.

The query is this:

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project1].[SupplierNumber] AS [SupplierNumber], 
    [Project1].[ArticleNumber] AS [ArticleNumber], 
    [Project1].[ArticleName] AS [ArticleName]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[SupplierNumber] AS [SupplierNumber], 
        [Extent1].[ArticleNumber] AS [ArticleNumber], 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[ArticleName] AS [ArticleName], 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM  [dbo].[SalesEntry] AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER LOOP JOIN [dbo].[Article] AS [Extent2]
            ON ([Extent1].[ArticleNumber] = [Extent2].[ArticleNumber])
                AND ([Extent1].[SupplierNumber] = [Extent2].[SupplierNumber])
        WHERE [Extent2].[id] IS NULL
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[SupplierNumber] ASC, [Project1].[ArticleNumber] ASC
  OPTION (TABLE HINT ([Extent1], INDEX(IX_Main)))
```

I have already annotated the query with two hints:

- the join is forced to be a loop join and
- I force an index that fits the order by criteria.

With these hints, I get an efficient query plan that looks like this:

> Scan index `IX_Main` on `SalesEntry` and for each 10 entries, look up the respective article entries with `IX_Main` on `Articles`.

Both tables have an `IX_Main` index on (`SupplierNumber`, `ArticleNumber`).

That way the query is fast.

Without the hints, however, Sql Server does a clustered index scan on `SalesEntry`, which is not useful at all, and an index scan on `IX_Main` for `Article`, and then brings the two streams together with a hash match.

That's not so fast, particularly because all the rows of `SalesEntry` now need to be scanned although we're only interested in the top 10 regarding `IX_Main`.

I'm confused as to why Sql Server would make that decision.

There's a `TOP 10` specifier. That should tell Sql Server that it can get enough rows for the result super-fast with the index it chooses to ignore (IX_Main). It then would need to do only a lousy ten lookups with the index `IX_Main` on `Article`.

I already tried and failed to reduce this to a simple example that can be reproduced, so I'm putting this with as much information out there as I think it relevant.

Does anyone have an idea about what Sql Server's thought process might be?

(The query looks a bit weird as it is based on what my ORM, Entity Framework produces.)

EDIT: Here's the problematic plan as [xml in a gist](https://gist.github.com/jtheisen/8da704a10fcce8fbba152489507ddc73).

Comment: Does the problem plan have a literal `10` or is it parameterized? If you try `TOP 1` or `TOP 2` do you get the plan that you would expect? Do you have trace flag 4138 enabled?

Comment: Literal 10 (from SSMS), `TOP 1` has the same plan, trace flag tested and it being on or off makes no difference to the plan.

Comment: Are you able to share the problematic plan (as XML)? - Also might be worth looking at the XML and verifying that no plan guides have been applied. Another question - when you do force the nested loops plan what is the estimated number of executions for the inner side?

Comment: It is not clear what the problem query is from your question.  If looks the the changes are in the query.

Comment: @MartinSmith I put the xml of the bad plan up. Interestingly, the estimated number of executions for the inner side is 334348, but the actual ones are only 4 (with a top 1). The estimate is a bit more than half the total rows. For some reason Sql Server thinks it will have to look at half the articles before it finds 10 that doesn't have one.

Comment: I guess that explains it then - presumably the 334,348 executions plan has a higher cost and so isn't selected. You're basically doing a `NOT EXISTS` query. I'm not sure of the exact gory details about how it calculates the expected probability of a row existing or not existing in a second table. AFAIK generally it errs towards expecting it to exist though ("the containment assumption")

Answer (score 1):

That top being kind of removed from the order by makes is hard for the query optimizer
It does not need to just do a lousy 10 lookups as it need top 10  WHERE [Extent2].[id] IS NULL
With more statistics the query optimizer may get smarter
I know you are using an ORM but give this a try

```
SELECT  Top(10) 1 AS [C1],
        [Extent1].[SupplierNumber] AS [SupplierNumber], 
        [Extent1].[ArticleNumber]  AS [ArticleNumber], 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[ArticleName] AS [ArticleName]
        FROM [dbo].[SalesEntry] AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Article] AS [Extent2]
            ON [Extent1].[ArticleNumber]  = [Extent2].[ArticleNumber]
           AND [Extent1].[SupplierNumber] = [Extent2].[SupplierNumber]
WHERE [Extent2].[id] IS NULL
ORDER BY [Extent1].[SupplierNumber] ASC, [Extent1].[ArticleNumber] ASC
```

Comment: Ah, of course you're right - the where clause makes it completely uncertain how many rows from `SalesEntry` need to be tested. (The unwrapping of the query makes no difference though, already tried that.)

Comment: Even if it unwrap does not help post an easier to read query does help